# Try showing error when $.parseJSON throws error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

when I get some data from server which cannot be parsed try block dies kills the page in IE8

```
 var statusData='';
            try
            {
                statusData = $.parseJSON(responseText);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                statusData = $.parseJSON( '[message=>"Some error occured",Status=>false]');
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your `catch` can just be replaced with what I'm assuming is

```
statusData = { message: "Some error occured", Status: false };
```

You have a PHP serialized array in place of a JSON string, which is why you are getting that error.